# Nifi logs stopped updating

Tags: logging, apache-nifi

I have Nifi adminstered by HDF 3.4.1.1, running on a single node. The nifi-app.log has stopped updating

```
ls /var/log/nifi2
nifi-app_2019-07-07_10.0.log  nifi-app_2019-07-07_15.0.log  nifi-app_2019-07-07_20.0.log   nifi-setup.log            nifi-user_2019-06-20.log  nifi-user_2019-06-28.log
nifi-app_2019-07-07_11.0.log  nifi-app_2019-07-07_16.0.log  nifi-app_2019-07-07_21.0.log   nifi-user_2019-06-07.log  nifi-user_2019-06-24.log  nifi-user_2019-07-03.log
nifi-app_2019-07-07_12.0.log  nifi-app_2019-07-07_17.0.log  nifi-app.log                   nifi-user_2019-06-10.log  nifi-user_2019-06-25.log  nifi-user_2019-07-04.log
nifi-app_2019-07-07_13.0.log  nifi-app_2019-07-07_18.0.log  nifi-bootstrap_2019-06-27.log  nifi-user_2019-06-11.log  nifi-user_2019-06-26.log  nifi-user_2019-07-05.log
nifi-app_2019-07-07_14.0.log  nifi-app_2019-07-07_19.0.log  nifi-bootstrap.log             nifi-user_2019-06-19.log  nifi-user_2019-06-27.log  nifi-user.log
```

There are nifi flows actively running since 07-07. How can I get logs flowing again and debug this issue?

The last entry in the nifi-app.log is:

````
2019-07-07 22:59:59,544 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-14] o.a.n.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask Administratively Yielding ListS3```
````

Comment: nifi uses logback for logging. search for `logback stopped` solutions over the internet. check the docs for file appender:  https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender

Comment: I found in the Ambari logs that the permissions on the folder /var/log/nifi weren't allowing the user nifi to create logs. I'm not sure what triggered this change (from /var/log/nifi2/ to /var/log/nifi) but after running chown on the folder it's now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was already provided by the asker in the comments:

I found in the Ambari logs that the permissions on the folder /var/log/nifi weren't allowing the user nifi to create logs. I'm not sure what triggered this change (from /var/log/nifi2/ to /var/log/nifi) but after running chown on the folder it's now working